# New onAttach() in API Level 23

Tags: android, android-fragments

It seems the Old `onAttach()` API is [deprecating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)) and instead apps need to make use of New `onAttach()` which takes `Context` as its parameter (in earlier `onAttach()`, it was `Activity`).

Does this mean, going forward, Fragments can also be associated with more contexts other than Activity(may be services or broadcast receivers)?

How this can be useful for developers?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean, going forward, Fragments can also be associated with more contexts other than Activity(may be services or broadcast receivers)?

No. Fragment only can be associated with activity. From the docs:

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

---

> instead apps need to make use of New onAttach() which takes Context as its parameter (in earlier onAttach(), it was Activity)

I think, Google is too paranoid on picking inappropriate `Activity`'s context. For example, `AppCompatActivity`, `FragmentActivity`, `ActionBarActivity`, while `onAttch(Activity)` takes `Activity` as its parameter. So that, Google change `Activity` with `Context` which is more global.

Comment: hard to get the reason why google may have introduced an api with diff parameter unless there is rational behind it